# Recording tool for tesing android applications

Tags: android, testing, android-testing

Is there any application that I can use to record user activity with android applications?

I want to get the user steps when they are testing the application. Is it possible to record their steps (maybe as screenshots)?

Comment: No, I mean like many similar testing tools that record tester's activity when testing pc applications.

Comment: You could record the hole testing action with an Android Record Screen tool.

Comment: @viperbone can you suggest me any of these tools?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the LogCat. At every step you want to record, print something to the LogCat

```
Log.D("Button Press", "User touched the 'View More' button);
```

And then using the  LogCollectors source code (http://code.google.com/p/android-log-collector/
) you can email it to yourself and conduct your analysis.

Alternatively, you could try to use monkeyrunner (http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html) and create a script that runs and takes screen shots while the user uses the application [not sure if that would work - have never used it].

I would think for the purposes of collecting data, using the logcat would be a smoother and more detailed process.

Comment: Thanks, but I want a tool to run outside the application under test. And of course LogCat requires changes on our code (which is not QA team's responsibility.